# Bug in Z3 JAVA-API to set timeout

Tags: java, timeout, z3

```
Context ctx = getZ3Context();
solver = ctx.MkSolver();
Params p = ctx.MkParams();
p.Add("soft_timeout", 1);
solver.setParameters(p);
```

Z3 will stop in 10 secs of a particular benchmark, no matter what I set for "soft_timeout".

Answer (score 1):

See the following related questions:

- [Z3 JAVA-API for solver timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513944/z3-java-api-for-solver-timeout/15518185#15518185)
- [Z3 C API Changing Timeout at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833925/z3-c-api-changing-timeout-at-runtime)
- [Incorrect Behavior for tactic solver for timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439894/incorrect-behavior-for-tactic-solver-for-timeout)
- [Z3 Timeout with Solver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854664/z3-timeout-with-solver/10857011#10857011)